# Text behind div / image

Tags: html, css, sass

I just want to have some text behind 3 images.
These 3 images should be next to each other (in a row) an when I hover they should rotate and the text behind appears.

Now i have the problem that i cant get those 3 divs next to each other (but the text behind the images :) )

Html:

```
<div id="teamContent">
    <div class="teamMember">
        <h3>name</h3>
        <h4>job</h4>
        <img src="images/team.jpg" alt="teamImage"/>
    </div>
    <div class="teamMember">
        <h3>name</h3>
        <h4>job</h4>
        <img src="images/team.jpg" alt="teamImage"/>
    </div>
    <div class="teamMember">
        <h3>name</h3>
        <h4>job</h4>
        <img src="images/team.jpg" alt="teamImage"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#teamContent{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    .teamMember{
        width: 30%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px;
        img{
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

tried to do a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2k2dvhv0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is to dont use float, flex is better, there's a help:

```
<div id="teamContent">
    <div class="teamMember">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="teamImage">
        <div class="data">
          <h3>name</h3>
          <h4>job</h4> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="teamMember">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="teamImage"/>       
        <div class="data">
        <h3>name</h3>
        <h4>job</h4>  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="teamMember">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="teamImage"/>
        <div class="data">
        <h3>name</h3>
        <h4>job</h4>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#teamContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.teamMember {
  text-align: center;
}
.data {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.teamMember:hover .data {
  opacity: 1;
}
.teamMember img {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
.teamMember:hover img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9Lh7aqs/

Comment: Thanks, just have to add that the text is really behind the image and appears only when mouseover

Answer (score 0):

Here solved https://jsfiddle.net/2k2dvhv0/7/

use floats to position your divs put the

```
<div>
```

you want in the middle behind the other `<div>`